# Using VPN service through proxy server (ISA)

Tags: vpn, proxy, isa

I have 10 users on my office network and don't want to setup VPN on each client's PC. Is it possible to configure VPN service (Hotspot Shield, Hidemyass or even I can setup my own VPN server on a dedicated server in a datacenter) in ISA (proxy server) and all (or domain based traffic) route through that VPN service.

My proxy server is running on Windows Server.

Answer (score 0):

You can configure your ISA Server to work as a VPN Server too. You don't need any other software.

﻿http://support.microsoft.com/kb/837355

If your office network consists of a domain then you could easily setup VPN connections on your clients via group policy & powershell scripts. If not, you could just give them the script to run.

﻿http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee431700(v=ws.10).aspx